# How to use an external command in Vim to modify selected words and lines?

Tags: external-command

Something I've found useful in other editors is the ability to:

- take the selected text
- run an external command and pass the selection to its `stdin`
- take the external commands `stdout` and replace the current selection with it.

*This way you can write useful text tools which operate on the selection using any language that can do basic io.*

How can this be done with vim using the selection?
... a single character, word, paragraph... etc.

(Directly in the command line, or via a key binding?)

---

### Note

Commands such as `!sort` work on the line-level, the reason I'm asking this question is because I would like to operate on the selection. (i.e., the text that would be removed if `x` was pressed).

Answer (score 29):

I find that often the easiest way is to use visual mode with <kbd>v</kbd> (or capital <kbd>V</kbd> to select whole lines), and select the text you want to pipe.

Then type:

```
:!cat
```

This doesn't do anything useful, as such. A useful command I use often is:

```
:!python -m json.tool
```

to format JSON.

You can also just type (without visual mode):

```
:<range>!command
```

For example, for the entire file:

```
:%!python -m json.tool
```

Or for the current line:

```
:.!python -m json.tool
```

Comment: Another really useful tool to use with this is the `sort` command.

Comment: @CodyPoll What's wrong with Vim's `:sort`?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker The external sort command has a lot more options and (depending on locale, etc.) produces a different order.

Comment: This doesn't work for selecting a single word in a line. (see question mentions word level selection)

Comment: @ideasman42 Right ... I think I originally read this question as "lines *or* words" instead of "lines *and* words" ... In any case, doing this with words is non-obvious, UNIX programs work on lines, and Vim is no exception. I did some experimenting and sort of have a solution, but it doesn't work very well ... Maybe my approach is wrong, so I'll just leave it be for a few days and get back to it later.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker not sure UNIX programs working on lines is related. QtCreator for example has this ability to send the selection to the stdout and then replace it with the stdin. It can be a single character or many lines (only the selected portions of partially selected lines). So I think it should be possible to do with vim, without a lot of trouble.

Comment: @ideasman42 What I meant was, that this is how Vim (specifically `!`) behaves. If you want different behaviour, you'll have to code it manually (I can't find anything built-in for it), and that this is probably because most UNIX programs work on lines.

Comment: Great answer, but as an amendment, for most systems `jq '.'` can be used in place of `python -m json.tool`. Just saves a bit of typing, and it's a great CLI tool overall.

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a plugin called [express.vim](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-express) that can help with this. The plugin defines an operator `g=` that lets you evaluate a VimScript expression over a motion (or Visual selection). It prompts for an expression, in which you can use `v:val` as a placeholder for the text covered by the motion (or, again, Visual selection).

In this case, a useful expression would use the `system()` function, which runs an external command.

```
system('tr a-z A-Z', v:val)
```

(Here I used `tr` as a simple example external command.)

The way to use express.vim for this problem would be to select the text with Visual mode, then type `g=` followed by that expression, then hit `Enter`:

```
g=system('tr a-z A-Z', v:val)<CR>
```

I'll admit, it's not easy to use. (In fact, I rarely use this plugin myself!) I'm considering adding a shortcut to invoke an external command, such as starting the expression with `!`. I'll post an update here if I end up doing that.

**EDIT**

I've modified express.vim to treat expressions beginning with `!` as external commands. So, sticking with the `tr` example, the above becomes a lot simpler. After a Visual selection, type the following:

```
g=!tr a-z A-Z<CR>
```

Explanation:

1. Invoke the express operator with `g=`
2. Enter `!tr a-z A-Z` as the expression
3. Press `Enter`

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the filter commands in Vim. See `:help filter`. Here is the relevant documentation:

```
!{motion}{filter}   Filter {motion} text lines through the external
                    program {filter}.
!!{filter}          Filter [count] lines through the external program
                    {filter}.
{Visual}!{filter}   Filter the highlighted lines through the external
                    program {filter} (for {Visual} see |Visual-mode|).
                    {not in Vi}

:{range}![!]{filter} [!][arg]               *:range!*
                    Filter {range} lines through the external program
                   {filter}.  ...[See documentation for details]
```

So typing `5!!sort` will sort the next 5 lines starting from the cursor.

Comment: Is it possible to filter a single word? (not line level)

Comment: Yes. The third option (visual mode) works for whatever is highlighted (words, partial line, multiple lines, rectangular block, etc.).

Comment: The third option also filters entire lines. If you select a single word and filter it, for example, through `tr [:lower:] [:upper]`, than vim will upcase not just this word but the entire line.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it can be done with:

1. visually select whatever you wish
2. `s^R=system('tr a-z A-Z', @")[:-2]^M` (with `^R` being CTRL+R, and ^M being ENTER)

It could also work with anything that does selection + replace like `ci"^R=...`.

Comment: When running this on a multi line text selection (after pressing `v` and moving the cursor) I get the error `E16: Invalid range\nE16: Invalid range\nE476: Invalid command` (on Linux so `tr` and other basic commands exist).

Comment: Have you pressed `s` that goes into insert mode or `:s` the command?

Comment: Suspect not, but also not sure how you mean, perhaps the example could show how to bind this to a key?

Comment: Do you hit directly `s` from the visual mode, or do you hit `:` first? There is no `:` involved in the sequence of keys I've written. A mapping would be: `vnoremap µ s<c-r>=system('tr a-z A-Z', @")[:-2]<cr>`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a vim plugin called vis.vim which allows this functionality. I found it on this stack overflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072761/vim-send-visual-block-to-external-command#answer-40083050

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Good answers include more than just a link and a vague description; they should stand on their own. You can [edit] to improve your answer, if you wish :)